# "Multi-consequent" Decision graph/tree?

Tags: decision-problem

As I understand, **Decision graph** is a directed graph where each vertex is a "**Question**" (decision to make), and each edge is an "**Answer**" (decision made for the vertex this edge is coming from). The terminal nodes of that graph is a solution.

Problem: With this structure - each "Answer" can lead only to a single consequent "Question". However in my real-world problem **"Answer" can lead to multiple consequent "Questions"**.

What is the right data structure and algorithms for such kind of decision making , finding optimal solution problems.

Comment: It's still a decision tree. You can put several questions at one vertex.

Comment: Not exactly. Imagine you have 2 consequent questions with 3 answers each. How will you fit it in one node? How many resolutions you will have?

Comment: You will have $3^2=9$ resolutions.

Comment: Exactly - that will be a Cartesian product of all sets of answers on the same level, so it's not very nice. Is there any better data structure/algorithm for that?